# Firebase firestore security rule access path params

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Consider this piece of security rules

```js
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /notifications/{user} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
    match /items/{item} {
      allow read: if true;
      allow write: if false
    }
  }
}
```

I want to access the parameter {item}'s value. Is there any way to do that? For a cloud function it would be something like 'context.params.item'. I need something similar for firestore security rules.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query), that parameter is stored under the [`resource.data`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Resource) variable:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /notifications/{user} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
    match /items/{item} {
      allow read: if resource.data != null;
      allow write: if false
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes I can access the value at the path '/items/{item}' using the resource object. But I don't want that. For example if the path is '/items/23' and it may hold some data like '{name: 'orange', price: 5}'. I can access this easily through the resource object. But i want to know the last part of the path i.e. the value '23'.

Comment: Then you might wanna use `resource.id`

Answer (score 0):

[Writing conditions for Cloud Firestore Security Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions)

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    // Make sure the uid of the requesting user matches name of the user
    // document. The wildcard expression {userId} makes the userId variable
    // available in rules.
    match /users/{userId} {
      allow read, update, delete: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId;
      allow create: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

As the comment explained, in your case since {item} is embraced, just use **item** in the rule.